# Parsing csv file using pandas leads to TypeError in strptime()

Tags: python, pandas, strptime

I'm trying to process data in a csv file, using pandas. I want to add up the data every 15 minutes. After doing some coding, I keep getting this error.

```
'dt = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int'
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong and how to fix it?
Here is my code and data.By the way, the format of DateTimeKey is like 2016-06-11 22:15:00.000

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data =pd.read_csv('C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test.csv')  

def time_format(x):
    dt = datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')    
    mod = (dt.minute // 15)
    if mod == 0:
        if dt.minute == 0:
            return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, dt.minute,
dt.second, dt.microsecond)
        else:
            minute = mod * 15
            return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, minute, 
dt.second, dt.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=15)
    else: 
        minute = mod * 15
        return datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, dt.hour, minute, 
dt.second,dt.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=15)

df = data.fillna(0)
df['DateTimeKey'] = df['DateTimeKey'].apply(time_format)
print(df.groupby('DateTimeKey', as_index=False).sum())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy0Uo.png)

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I suspect we need a sample data file - or even better a sample df to figure this out

Comment: Well, what does the documentation of the `strptime` function say?

Comment: `df = data.fillna(0)` is probably converting a missing datetime string into `0`.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help! Roganjosh is right, I made a stupid mistake that I forgot to check whether there is a missing datetime string. Thanks all of you! Have a good night!